# How can I find the critical dimension for the Blum-Capel model near the tricritical point in mean field theory?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, spin-models, critical-phenomena

I believe that I have found the critical dimension for the critical temperatures on the critical line (that is, where the second order phase transition occurs), which is $D=4$. This is because the critical exponent related to the correlation distance is $\nu=1/2$ and the critical exponent $\alpha=0$. Therefore I find from a dimensional analysis of the propagator that $\frac{1}{R^2}\xi^{2-D}\ll\left(\frac{R}{\xi}\right)^2$ and thus for the mean field approximation to be valid we must have $D>4$. Near the tricritical point I found that the critical index $\alpha=1/2$, but this leads me to $D>5$ whereas I should have $D>3$. I would really appreciate if you could suggest me some sources where i can learn about a derivation of the critical dimension for the tricritical point or post the derivation in the answers.

I do not know any statistical field theory or renormalization group theory.

Comment: Have you checked out John Cardy's book, https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/scaling-and-renormalization-in-statistical-physics/924C0B0D39123F681CF3353C42E5E836, where in Chapter 4, he talks about the phase diagram of the Blum-Capel model and the cross-over phenomenon.